# Passing selected arguments from a dictionary to a function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

Given a set of functions that differ in their signatures and a dictionary that contains (key, value) pairs for each of the required arguments, I want to find an elegant way of passing the dictionary to each function, so that each function may use the parameters from the function it requires.

```py
def first_function(name, age):
    print(name, " ", age)

def second_function(name, gender):
    print(name, " ", gender)

param_dict = {'name': 'Max', 'age': 23, 'gender':'m'}
```

Passing the `param_dict` to the function by specifying `second_function(**param_dict)` throws an error as neither function requires for all three parameters. Is there an elegant solution, such that each functions 'extracts' the parameters it requires?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply pass `**kwargs` as a third arg to get around this problem, since it will consume what it needs out of the dictionary, the rest will remain collected in the `kwargs` dict:

```py
def first_function(name, age, **kwargs):
    print(name, age)

def second_function(name, gender, **kwargs):
    print(name, gender)

param_dict = {'name': 'Max', 'age': 23, 'gender':'m'}

first_function(**param_dict)
# Max 23

second_function(**param_dict)
# Max m
```